# Joomla Plugin With Helper File

Tags: plugins, joomla

Is there a conventional way of making a helper file to a Joomla Plugin? Like class names (helper or plgNameHelper) and the way of calling it?

```
class Helper
{
    public static function test() 
    {
    // some code
    }

    public static function anotherTest() 
    {
    // some code
    }
}
```

Comment: You can close this question as it was answered on Joomla Stack Exchange ;)

Answer (score 0):

Conventionally, helper files have been for modules, not plugins. However it is a good idea to make a template, if the plugin changes the page HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There is no conventional way of making a helper file to a Joomla Plugin but you can create Joomla! Library which can help you to auto load your classes by registering prefix.

I suggest you to read [this](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_own_library_in_your_extensions) link.